# Can you use the most recent versions of Angular (6, 7, 8) on React Native?

Tags: angular, react-native, phonegap

I'm thinking of creating an app in Phonegap with Angular 2, and then eventually (2 years time) porting it to React Native (as I heard Phonegap is easier for beginner devs).

I want to know if I'm stuck with using Angular 2 for PG + RN, as I've searched but everything I've seen just says "Angular 2 works on React Native", and says nothing about newer versions. I'm not even sure if the new versions of Angular work on Phonegap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly advise against trying to mix angular with react native. There maybe a couple of articles that say it's doable and maybe it is but react native was built to use the react library.

Reasons why you should not mix both (if you're building a serious app):

1. They both are different JS frameworks (library in react's case) and mainly not meant to be used together
2. If you end up mixing react native and angular you might run into problems that are not that common due to the fact that the majority of people do not mix these technologies.
3. Support would be minimal hence you might get stuck at a point without being able to find any way out (or waste a lot of your time).

There are a couple options for hybrid/native mobile development; like React Native, Native Script, Ionic and Flutter. Porting from one to the other will often mean rewriting a lot if not most of it for the framework you're porting to.

If you would like to build a mobile app with angular I would recommend going with Ionic 4 + Capacitor. If you already know angular I believe this is the simplest way to start.

Comment: Thanks, that info is really helpful. Though I've never used Angular before, and am still learning Javascript. Do you still think Ionic 4 is the easiest option?

Comment: Depends on your needs but in general people say Angular has a steeper learning curve compared to React. You can use ionic 4 with react although that's a new addition. Ionic in general might be easier to pickup because you're basically building a web application that wrapped in a mobile app, hence you write once and run anywhere. While react native compiles to native code. Your iOS and android code will share a lot code but not everything.